# Python / PyPlot- How can I specify the x/y-axis on plt.imshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Often when I want to visualise 3D data I do the following

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y = np.mgrid[:10, :20]
z = x**2 + y
plt.imshow(z)
plt.show()
```

The problem with this is that often I want to set the x and y variables instead of being "pixels". I know `plt.contourf` does what I want but the problem with that is the quality is no where near as good as `plt.imshow`

The solution I'm trying to work towards is getting the `plt.contourf` syntax to work for `plt.imshow`.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

The solution should also work on the following use case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R, P = np.mgrid[:10, :2*np.pi:np.pi/50]
plt.contourf(R*np.cos(P), R*np.sin(P), R) # <--- need better function
# plt.imshow(R*np.cos(P), R*np.sin(P), R) #      something like this
plt.show()
```

Comment: I added some info to the question, and from briefly looking at extent I don't think it works for the new use case I posted

Comment: Then please ask a new question asking your actual question.  I suspect the answer will be meshgrid.

Comment: the answer is closer to `plt.contourf(R*np.cos(P), R*np.sin(P), R, N)` where N is ~50. I waould somehow like to open the question to post this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to do what I want is to use the `plt.contourf`

so the following would do what I want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R, P = np.mgrid[:10, :2*np.pi:np.pi/50]
N = 50
plt.contourf(R*np.cos(P), R*np.sin(P), R, N) # <--- need better function
plt.pcolormesh(R*np.cos(P), R*np.sin(P), R) # <--- exactly what I want
# plt.imshow(R*np.cos(P), R*np.sin(P), R) #      something like this
plt.show()
```

Tweaking `N` gets you a good enough image in `contourf`. The only thing I don't like about this is the very fact you might need to tweak the `N` value.